# Wrapping four items in an output div, taking into account the remainder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried a few methods to get this working but I seem to be missing something.

I have a `for` loop which iterates through an object and outputs a picture for each object by appending it to a wrapper `#staff-list-wrapper`. It currently outputs 35 images inside their own `.staff-item` div.

```
for(var i=0;i<staffArray.length;i++){
    var img = '<div class="staff-item"><img id="'+staffArray[i].slug+'" src="'+staffArray[i].pic_url+'" /></div>';
    $('#staff-list-wrapper').append(img);
}
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<div id="staff-list-wrapper">
    <div class="staff-item">
        <img id="felicity" src="http://localhost/something/wp-content/uploads/about_us_Felicity.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="staff-item">
        <img id="hannah" src="http://localhost/something/wp-content/uploads/about_us_Hannah.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to wrap every four `.staff-item` divs in another div, `.staff-row`

However I also need to bear in mind that because the number of items may not be divisible by 4, I might need to end a row early (with only 1, 2 or 3 `.staff-item`'s inside)

So I understand I can use the `modulo` operator to check for remainder from a /4 calculation.

However I cannot quite seem to get the logic correct to input the images *inside* these rows. I am able to output enough rows for every 4 items (9 rows in this case):

```
var rowCount = 1;
if(i % 4 === 0 ){
   $('#staff-list-wrapper').append('<div class="staff-row" id="staff-row-'+rowCount+'" ></div>');
}
```

This creates 9 rows. How can I get every four items inside that row?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. I am sure there are more elegant ways to solve this but here was my initial solution.

```
<?php
$testArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

$numberOfElementsInArray = count($testArray);
$positionInArray = 0; // need to save our position
$howManyForFullSet = 4; // pick how many items you want in each set

$fullSets = floor($numberOfElementsInArray / $howManyForFullSet);
$remaining = $numberOfElementsInArray % $howManyForFullSet;

echo "number of elements in array = " . $numberOfElementsInArray;
echo "\n";
echo "full sets of (" . $howManyForFullSet . ") = " . $fullSets;
echo "\n";
echo "remaining elements = " . $remaining;
echo "\n";
echo "\n";


for ($i = $fullSets; $i > 0; $i--) { // loop for each full set

    for ($j = $howManyForFullSet; $j > 0; $j--) { // each element in set
        echo($testArray[$positionInArray]);
        $positionInArray += 1;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
if ($remaining !== 0) {
    for ($k = $remaining; $k > 0; $k--) { // if we have remainder items display them
        echo($testArray[$positionInArray]);
        $positionInArray += 1;
    }
}
```